# Решите задачу на С++

Tags: c++

Для скольких из 22-х заданных цифр 2000, 2001, ..., 2021 существует натуральное число, которое имеет произведение цифр, равной соответствующему заданному числу?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    unsigned long long int res=1;
    unsigned long long int num=6666;

    

        while(true)
        {
            res = 1;
            string th = to_string(num);

            for (int j = 0; j < th.length(); ++j)
            {
                char a[2] = { th[j],'\0' };
                res *= atoi(a);
            }
            

            for (int i = 2000; i <= 2021; i++)
            {
                if (res == i)
                {
                    cout << "\a" << res << endl;
                    //Sleep(999);
                }
            }
            num++;
            
        }
    
    

    
    
    Sleep(9999999);
}
```

Comment: Вы не поняли задание. Для числа 2000 одним из ответов будет число 2222555. Если перемножите цифры второго, то получите первое.

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите полный код вашей попытки (TO DO - не считается), чтобы мы его исправили.

Comment: хорошоооооооооо

Comment: Цифр всего десять :) В отличие от чисел.

Comment: Подсказка: `2000 -> 25558`, `2016 -> 4789`. А какие есть ещё, не скажу.

Comment: ух ты! в чем же секрет?

Comment: Всё уже сказано в комментариях и в ответе.

Comment: получается, 2000 и 2016 только эти цифры?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy запустите мой код. Выводиться только 2000 и 2016

Comment: значит ответ - 2?

Comment: Так не пойдет. Ваш код не завершается. Подождите, вдруг что-нибудь ещё найдётся?

Comment: да все правильно! Теперь вопрос - почему на мой вопрос ставили стрелочки вниз?

Comment: Вы не поняли как решать задачу. А когда поняли, решили не полностью. Думаю, ваш вопрос скоро закроют.

Comment: ехх, придётся удалять. Спасибо всем за помощь!

Comment: ах не могу удалить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разложите каждое число, которое проверяете, на простые множители. Если все простые множители меньше десяти - для этого числа существует.

```
2000 - 2*2*2*2*5*5*5 - существует
2001 - 3*23*29       - не существует
```

Comment: Можно и так, но, честно говоря, простые - это слишком. Просто поделить на все цифры до упора. Если уперлись в единицу, то да, иначе - нет.

Comment: благодарю! мой код походу правильный?